# Puppeteer fails to execute from Crontab but works when executing manually from terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, centos, puppeteer

I want to make a Node.js Puppeteer cronjob, but Puppeteer breaks without any errors only when executed from a cronjob.

The script I'm trying works perfectly when executed manually (by Terminal) from it's root folder, but something seems to go wrong whenever I try to execute it as a cronjob and the execution stops.

I made some console.logs to help me situate the problem and found out that the script's execution breaks right at `const browser = await puppeteer.launch()`.
Anything after it just doesn't execute.

See code below to get what I'm talking about:

```js
'use strict'

console.log('Node script starts!');

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

    console.log('test 1');
    //Code stops here

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    console.log('test 2');

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
    await page.screenshot({
        path: '0_ScreenShot.png'
    });

    await browser.close();
})();
```

So executing the above code manually through SSH by doing:

```
[site@server ~]$ cd public_html/test/
```

Then:

```
[site@server test]$ nohup node ctest.js > out.log &
```

My `out.log` file outputs the following and saves a screenshot under `/test/0_ScreenShot.png` which is the expected result:

```
Node script starts!
test 1
test 2
```

But for some reason, which is why I'm here, executing that same file through a cronjob does not work, the `out.log` prints only the following:

```
Node script starts!
test 1
```

The cronjob in question is setup from the cPanel as :

```
./bin/node ./public_html/test/ctest.js > ./public_html/test/out.log &
```

I thought it was a path problem and tried to be as absolute as possible by changing the Puppeteer initialization to this but without luck:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: '/home/site/public_html/test/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-654752/chrome-linux/chrome'
    });
```

I even downloaded a fresh Chromium and used it but still nothing:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: '/home/site/public_html/test/node_modules/chromium/lib/chromium/chrome-linux/chrome'
    });
```

I used a bash script (`shell_node.sh`) to execute the node script but the same issue persisted:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
nohup ./bin/node ./public_html/test/ctest.js > ./public_html/test/out.log &
```

Cron:

```
bash ./public_html/test/shell_node.sh
```

I also tried executing the script by PHP using the `exec()` function, nothing still.

I looked everywhere for a solution, but it feels like I'm the first person ever to have come across this specific issue.. which is worrying, but I'm hoping someone from here might answer me.

Thank you for your read and your time.

Comment: Most probably the problem is that `puppeteer` was not imported because you're not using the correct working directory, look into how to set the working directory for a cronjob.

Comment: Is there anything in the syslog about the issue?

Comment: @Titus Thank you for your suggestion, I'm still trying to work with it but no luck for now

Comment: @Vaviloff There's no syslog available unfortunately

Comment: @ZachRachedi Currently, you are only logging `stdout` and not `stderr` where the error is likely printed to. You should change your line to `./bin/node ... > stdout.log 2> stderr.log` to also log the error. The error will probably give you a hint what is going wrong, otherwise we can help you ;)

Comment: @ZachRachedi did you get this to work? I'm battling a similar issue.

Comment: @mpc75 Hey, sorry for the late reply. I solved it but I forgot what was the exact problem I found but after looking into my code I found that I used this while declaring the browser:
`const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});`
I set up error login by email and received the proper Exceptions that were happening and saw it was coming from the chrome instance setup as a sandbox.
Let me know if it helps and good luck!

Comment: @ZachRachedi thanks for the response :) Good to know, I ended up solving my issue, which was due to an OS security setting. Much appreciated, though!